# What is the purpose of the winglets on the Socata TB-31 Omega vertical stabilizer?

Tags: aircraft-design, winglets

Aérospatiale-Socata built a prototype of the TB-31 for the French Air Force, which never went to production:

[image]
<sup>Source: [netAirspace.com](https://www.netairspace.com/pic/34732/), photo by miamiair</sup>

What is the purpose of the winglets at the top of the vertical stabilizer?

Comment: I'd guess those are localizer antenna with an aerodynamic dielectric fairing.  Many aircraft are fitted with similar designs

Comment: They are likely VOR antennas.  Many Bonanzas and Cessnas have these as well.  The V-tails have them on the fuselage under the V.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you observe here are VHF nav antennas for a VOR receiver.  This antenna design is lower drag than wire whip antennas.

The antenna serves no aerodynamic purpose except to minimize its own drag profile.