# What is this "Micro T-tail" on the F-102?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter, feature-identification

I just noticed this unusual thing on the [F-102 Delta Dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_F-102_Delta_Dagger). It looks like a micro T-tail. What is it actually, and what is its purpose?

[image]

Comment: It’s an antenna.

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the winglets on the Socata TB-31 Omega vertical stabilizer?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38218/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The T tail is the VHF Antenna Localizer of the AN/ARN-31 Instrument Landing System.

[image]

source: [Convair F-102 Delta Dagger Pilot's Flight Operating Manual](https://books.google.de/books?id=v9NJ33r29LUC&pg=SA4-PA22&lpg=SA4-PA22&dq=antenna%20f102&source=bl&ots=RiyJgNueSq&sig=1jGPD7ZqXVwY-9DNCLcwlEjVIOs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCqKTB3djVAhWHVRQKHX4NBEUQ6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q&f=false)