# What is this flat plate sticking out of the tail of Learjet 24D?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, feature-identification

What is this protrusion on the tail of Learjet 24D (shown just above the avro museum logo) and what is its function?

[image]
*Learjet 24D Tail closeup*

[image]
*Zoomed out image of the Learjet tail*

Source: images were taken by yours truly

Comment: More importantly, how are they going to continue their tennis match now that the ball has been impaled on the wing tip?!???!?!  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a VOR antenna. You can find more information about it in similar questions like [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38218/22871) or [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44330/22871).

Comment: Technically it's 1/2 of the VOR antenna.  There are two elements, one on each side of the tail.